# Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' in spring data rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, springfox

I am using spring data rest for my application.

I am getting following error and application doesn't get started when I add this method in repository:-

**Method:-**

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("from employee as ft where ft.company.id = ?1")
void deleteAllEmployeeCompany(
        @Param("companyId") @RequestParam("companyId") int companyId);
```

**Error:-**

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:874) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.1.RELEASE]
```

How to solve this ?

Updated:-

List of all dependencies:-

```
[INFO] com.test:test-service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:2.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-core:jar:2.5.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.atteo:evo-inflector:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:4.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.47:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.47:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:1.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-eventbus:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.10.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.servo:servo-internal:jar:0.10.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- com.netflix.governator:governator-api:jar:1.12.10:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core:jar:1.4.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.30:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ec2:jar:1.10.30:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-autoscaling:jar:1.9.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:jar:1.9.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-route53:jar:1.9.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.governator:governator:jar:1.12.10:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.governator:governator-core:jar:1.12.10:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-archaius:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-ribbon:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-transport:jar:2.1.5:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.reactivex:rxnetty-contexts:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty-servo:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |        +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |        +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |        \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.0.27.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-core:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-httpclient:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-commons-util:jar:0.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-loadbalancer:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-statistics:jar:0.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-eureka:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:1.6.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:3.6.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.rabbitmq:http-client:jar:1.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:1.6.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-javanica:jar:1.3.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-metrics-event-stream:jar:1.3.16:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-data-rest:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.20.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:3.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.34:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.json:json:jar:20140107:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.10:compile
[INFO]    +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO]    \- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:2.0.1:compile
```

Comment: Not positive this is it, but shouldn't `= ?1` actually be `= :companyId` in your query?

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70178343/springfox-3-0-0-is-not-working-with-spring-boot-2-6-0

Comment: @EnableWebMvc in main class worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70703081/5626568

Comment: spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher worked for me

Answer (score 231):

I got same issue using springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui version(3.0.0), spring-boot version(2.6.2)

The way to resolve this issue is by adding pathmatcher in application. properties or application.yml

### for application.properties:

spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER

### for application.yml:

```
spring:
    mvc:
      pathmatch:
            matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
```

Comment: Is there a documentation for this?

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: Didn't work for me on springfox-swagger-ui version(3.0.0) and spring-boot version(2.6.2) for some reason. Went down to spring-boot version(2.5.8) and resolved the issue without `spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER` in my application.properties

Comment: @CoderCal This solution worked for me: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3462#issuecomment-1010721223

Comment: Worked for me using spring boot 2.6.3

Comment: This wont work if you are using spring actuator

Comment: This worked for me as well on upgrading to spring boot 2.6

Comment: I tried multiple solutions,
but finally solved by the above solution
my spring version is 2.6.4 and I am also using a spring actuator
springfox-swagger2 - 3.0.0
springfox-boot-starter - 3.0.0
springfox-swagger-ui - 3.0.0

Comment: This solution worked for me with spring version 2.6.7  , all springfox dependencies 3.0.0

Comment: Worked with springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0 and spring-boot-starter:2.7.0

Comment: It worked for me on swagger version: '2.6.0'

Comment: Solved issue for me (`springfox-swagger2` version `3.0.0` & `spring-boot` version `2.7.4`).

Comment: Only changing application.properties worked for me.

Answer (score 70):

This issue is caused by `Spring Fox 3.0.0` not supporting new [PathPattern Based Path Matching Strategy for Spring MVC](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes#pathpattern-based-path-matching-strategy-for-spring-mvc) which is now the new default from `spring-boot 2.6.0`.

There are actually some workarounds for this issue like:

1. Downgrading `spring-boot` back to version lower than 2.6.0. **I wouldn't recommend that due to major security issues with older versions of spring boot / spring framework (like log4shell or CVE-2022-22965 for example.)**
2. Changing PathPattern matching back to AntPatternMatching in yml, like mentioned by [@santhanam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70503395/7974082).
3. `SpringFox` hasn't been updated for a year or so, so I would prefer remove it completely from a project and replace it with maintained [springdoc-openapi](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox) library. There is a section in `springdoc` documentation about migration from `SpringFox` and it's actually very straightforward to perform. And you'll get rid of issues caused by SpringFox completely.

Comment: Suggestion 3 should be the accepted answer IMO. Depending on a project that hasn't had attention in almost two years is not a wise move. As of now, no commits have been made on SpringFox since Oct 2020.

Comment: #3 is the best solution and I can confirm that the migration is indeed straight forward

Comment: Be careful with downgrading sping-boot since it may contain the old log4j versions with a serious exploid to JNDI-calls...

Comment: Whenever I read "downgrade", it makes my stomach turn.

Answer (score 29):

what I found was that spring is using mvcmatchers by default which conflicts with swagger because it uses the antmatchers so we can solve this by

## A

change spring to use antmatchers with configuring it
in application.properties

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

## B

enabling mvcmatchers in spring creating a config file for swagger to use

1. create a file for configs of swagger in anywhere you want
2. put these annotations

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger2
@Component
public class SwaggersConfigs {
}
```

## C

enableing mvcmatchers in all spring application with putting
@EnableWebMvc
annotation above the main class of spring boot aplication
like this

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger2
@SpringBootApplication
public class SwaggerDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SwaggerDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

## D

use older versions metioned in the other comments

Comment: This answer is from a legend.

Answer (score 24):

I got same issue using **springfox-swagger2** and **springfox-swagger-ui**
Switching back spring boot version from **2.6.0** to **2.5.2** Solved my issue.

> I know rolling back to older versions is not the best way to fix issues but helped me for now.

Comment: it solved my problem :) thank you

Comment: It solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing. This happened to me with open-api-generator integration which uses springfox for their implementations. I even I tried with spring boot version 2.6.2 updating springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui to the latest versions 3.0.x. No luck. Had to roll back to Spring boot 2.5.4 and 2.9.2 version of springfox. Hope in the future they fix this

Comment: spring boot 2.6.2 includes the recommended log4j 2.17 so this really needs to be fixed

Comment: it solved my problem, thanks. Changed the version as follows :     
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

Comment: With the new vulnerability Spring4Shell this solution is no longer a valid option.

Answer (score 12):

this works
Springboot version  2.6.0 and higher  does not support swagger 2
Remove springfox and swagger 2 dependencies. Add springdoc-openapi-ui dependency instead.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

add this to your application.properties file

spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER

after that navigate to
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

This worked for me

Comment: That's cool thing

Comment: This is a good solution if you can't move to Spring Boot 3 because you can't upgrade to Java 17.

Answer (score 11):

The reason for the error is swagger and spring-boot The version does not match

Remove All other dependencies and include only below one for swagger

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Add below Configurations :

For application.properties

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

For application.yml

```
spring:
    mvc:
      pathmatch:
            matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
```

Answer (score 11):

This solution fixed the issue along with the below property

**spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant_path_matcher**

I'm using spring boot **2.6.6**

Comment: This did trick for SpringBoot version 2.7.8. Tnx! :)

Answer (score 9):

In addition to setting the `matching-strategy` property, as mentioned by other answers, I also had to add the below bean to overcome this:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping webEndpointServletHandlerMapping(WebEndpointsSupplier webEndpointsSupplier, ServletEndpointsSupplier servletEndpointsSupplier, ControllerEndpointsSupplier controllerEndpointsSupplier, EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes, CorsEndpointProperties corsProperties, WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, Environment environment) {
    List<ExposableEndpoint<?>> allEndpoints = new ArrayList();
    Collection<ExposableWebEndpoint> webEndpoints = webEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints();
    allEndpoints.addAll(webEndpoints);
    allEndpoints.addAll(servletEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
    allEndpoints.addAll(controllerEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
    String basePath = webEndpointProperties.getBasePath();
    EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping(basePath);
    boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping = this.shouldRegisterLinksMapping(webEndpointProperties, environment, basePath);
    return new WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping(endpointMapping, webEndpoints, endpointMediaTypes, corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration(), new EndpointLinksResolver(allEndpoints, basePath), shouldRegisterLinksMapping, null);
}


private boolean shouldRegisterLinksMapping(WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties, Environment environment, String basePath) {
    return webEndpointProperties.getDiscovery().isEnabled() && (StringUtils.hasText(basePath) || ManagementPortType.get(environment).equals(ManagementPortType.DIFFERENT));
}
```

Solution found [here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3462#issuecomment-1010721223).

Answer (score 7):

I have got the same issue in spring boot version 1.5.3.RELEASE, but could resolve it by adding guava version 20.0.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

With Spring-Boot 2.6.0 and SpringFox 3.0.0 issue is pathmatcher, you can set pathmach with below property and this issue will be resolved

```
  spring:
        mvc:
          pathmatch:
                matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
```

Answer (score 7):

Just add this configuration to your application.properties

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

or if you using yaml file application.yml

```
spring:
mvc:
  pathmatch:
        matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
```

then Run your application.

You need to edit one part, the base package name. As shown in the screenshot my base package name.
[my package name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvLEJ.png)

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig2 {
    @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .enable(true)
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder()
                        .title("Swagger Super")
                        .description("Swagger Description details")
                        .version("1.0").build())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.swagger.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }
}
```

OR

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig2 {
    @Bean
    public Docket docket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .enable(true)
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder()
                        .title("Swagger Super")
                        .description("Swagger Description details")
                        .version("1.0").build())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(Api.class))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }
}
```

And the Swagger Dependencies

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

It's working fine

Also, you can define separately

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class Swagger2UiConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return (new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)).apiInfo(this.apiInfo()).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withMethodAnnotation(ApiOperation.class)).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return (new ApiInfoBuilder()).title("Swagger API").version("1.0").description("Swagger is Awesome").build();
    }
}
```

**Note:** SNAPSHOT, M1, M2, M3, and M4 releases typically WORK IN PROGRESS. The Spring team is still working on them, Recommend NOT using them.

**Note:** If want to implement springdoc-openAPI for the new version **spring-boot 3** then use the below-following dependency. That specific version would be working with **spring boot 3**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions or if there's anything else I can assist you with.

Happy coding! ‍

Comment: It solved my problem, I often copy my own answer to configure swagger. Very helpful

Answer (score 5):

As per official [doc](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#configuring-startup), adding below property in yaml resolved the issue for me.

```
springfox:
  documentation:
    auto-startup: false
```

Comment: This will fix the app starting issue but springfox will stop working ;). I think the only thing to do is to wait for a patch to springfox.

Answer (score 5):

removing old swagger dependencies and config classes.
using new springdoc dependency will help

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

a work around is to rollback to springfox-swagger2 2.5.0 .

Comment: For me, the newest working version of springfox-swagger2 is 2.8.0, so try rollbacking to that version. Works in combination with the newest released version of springfox-swagger-ui 2.9.2.

Comment: How a documentation tool can murder an application is totally beyond me. Irresponsible.

Comment: Thank you so much @MateŠimović the 2.8.0 thing worked for me with springfox-swagger-ui-2.9.2 and spring-boot-starter-parent 2.6.2!!

Answer (score 2):

i got similar issue and it was solved after follow [Springboot 2.6.0 / Spring fox 3 - Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036953/springboot-2-6-0-spring-fox-3-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsboot/70037507#70037507)

i was using spring 2.6.1 and springfox-swagger2 2.9.2.
"setting spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy to ant-path-matcher in your application.properties file"

Comment: Just to add this will not work if spring boot actuator dependency is there.
I had to remove the actuator dependency (losing the actuator endpoints of course).
and after adding this property with swagger version(s) up to 3.0.0 this worked

Answer (score 2):

With Spring-Boot 2.6.2 issue is pathmatcher, you can set pathmach with below property in application.properties file and this issue will be resolved

"spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I added @EnableWebMvc as decorator to my SwaggerConfig, which solved to problem.

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class SwaggerConfig {}
```

Versions: Sprint 2.6.1 and springfox-swagger* 2.9.2

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER` in the `application.properties` will hide just hide the javanull error which results in the White label error page. 
Use the following solution mentioned in the link 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76671291/17410605

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue seemed to be attempting to pass in an argument to a controller action (for a controller annotated with `RestController`) that was not getting resolved.

e.g.

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping(value = "/foo")
com.bestbuy.checkout.domain.Order foo(
    Bar justSomeObject
) {
```

Answer (score 1):

As per : https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2616 solution, I tried adding exclusion to recently added Lettuce library and it is working fine now. Only springfox guava dependency should be coming. As per this question something like below will work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
    <artifactId>hystrix-javanica</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.16</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had an issue like that in gradle. I solved it by removing all guava dependencies from springfox subdependecies:

```
implementation('io.springfox:springfox-spi:2.9.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
}

implementation('io.springfox:springfox-schema:2.9.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
}

implementation('io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:2.9.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
}
```

and implemented guava separately:

```
implementation('com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre')
```

My spring-boot version:

> 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the version of my project helped me.
Initially, I was using spring 2.6.0 but I moved to 2.5.2 and it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The general reason is that due to the springboot versioning, the default strategy for matching the request path and spring MVC processing mapping has been changed from antpathmatcher to pathpatternparser. This can be resolved by editing the properties.yml and adding

spring:
mvc:
pathmatch:
matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring boot 2.6 and trying to use springfox-swagger you will have a hard time.

If you are trying to have swagger documentation just use this dependency

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.4'
```

it will generate the doc for you that you can access using `/v3/api-docs` and the swagger-ui is accessible using `/swagger-ui/index.html`

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

change spring to use antmatchers with configuring it in application.properties in your spring boot project.

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("from employee as ft where ft.company.id = :companyId")
void deleteAllEmployeeCompany(
        @Param("companyId") @RequestParam("companyId") int companyId);
```

Or with SpEL

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("from employee as ft where ft.company.id = ?#{companyId}")
void deleteAllEmployeeCompany(
        @Param("companyId") @RequestParam("companyId") int companyId);
```

Check this https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions

Comment: I have tried your answer. But it results with same error.

Comment: I think the issue is related to spring-fox not to spring-data. `documentationPluginsBootstrapper` is a spring-fox component. What version of spring-fox are you using?

Comment: I am not using spring-fox in my application.

Comment: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/springfox-spring-web/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java

Comment: Please share the list of all dependencies.

Comment: As you can see you have this dependencies : io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.6.0:compile
...

Comment: Are you using swagger to document your api? If not remove these dependencies `io.springfox:springfox-swagger2` `io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui` `io.springfox:springfox-data-rest`

Comment: Yes. I am using swagger for API. Then how to proceed ?

Comment: Can you share spring configuration?

Comment: What do you mean by spring configuration ?

Comment: Configuration class where your added `@EnableWebMvc` and `@EnableSwagger2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126796/discussion-between-karan-and-issam-el-atif).

Comment: I run with the same issue and rollback to springfox 2.5.0 solves the issue (at least the application starts and every thing is okey). It looks that there's a bug intorudcued sine 2.6.0 of springfox

Answer (score 0):

I have a mircoservice environment, and I was adding swagger to all of them. I had the same issue, the solution [@Santhanam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70503395/5698765) worked for all the services except one. The service had `spring-boot-starter-actuator` as a dependency. Problem fixed by removing it.

It seems the config `spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER` **does not affect Spring Actuator auto-generated paths**.

For those who tried other answers and still have the problem, the solution is to remove Spring Actuator or to configure it in a way to use `ANT_PATH_MATCHER` as matching strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue easily. What we need to know is that Spinifex is no more up to date For more info click on this [link](https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html). Nowadays, you can use spring-doc,  by remplacing spring-fox dependencies with this dependency :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.8</version>
</dependency>

then add also this beans :
@Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi publicApi() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("springshop-public")
                .pathsToMatch("/public/**")
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi adminApi() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("springshop-admin")
                .pathsToMatch("/**")
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am using 2.7.6 version of spring boot and I was getting the same error. So I found the solution and check this; [Failed to start bean ‘documentationPluginsBootstrapper’ – use springdoc-openapi-ui](https://webfuse.in/blogs/issues-troubleshooting/org-springframework-context-applicationcontextexception-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsbootstrapper-nested-exception-is-java-lang-nullpointerexception/)

I added openapi dependency to my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Also added matching-strategy to my application.preperties or application.yml file;

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue in Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE and Spring Fox 3.0.0 just adding this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was with the spring actuator and I have upgraded my spring version to 2.7.1
Removing the spring actuator helped.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was fixed by below, during upgrade to 2.7 we have added docs profile in Application properties file and was enforcing springfox runtime.
Removing docs profile helped.
However if you wanted to use swagger docs using 2.7 feature then try using openapi lib.

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.15'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
```

https://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Answer (score 0):

## Latest update wokring with me

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Downgrading the Springboot version from 2.6.0 to 2.5.4 solves the issue, provided the below swagger version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```