# Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' Spring boot Swagger implementation using Spring Fox?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I am using springfox-boot-starter dependency for swagger UI in my spring boot application but when I try to run the application I am getting below error

```
    Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.getPluginFor(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/Optional;
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:184)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:52)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:157)
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:885)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
```

**my config file:**

```
 @Bean
 public Docket productApi() {
        
     return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.swagger.demo.controller"))
        .paths(regex("/student.*"))
        .build()
        .enableUrlTemplating(true)
        .produces(DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES)
        .consumes(DEFAULT_PRODUCES_AND_CONSUMES)
        .apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo());
    }

private ApiInfo apiEndPointsInfo() {

    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("demo")
            .description("demo")
            .version("1.0")
            .build();
}
```

Below is the dependency which I am using.
**pom.xml file:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
    
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Why I am getting above error I don't get anything. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper' in spring data rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241843/failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsbootstrapper-in-spring-data-rest)

Comment: Any update on this? Facing the same issue. Is any fix available?

Answer (score 26):

I had a similar issue and found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036953/springboot-2-6-0-spring-fox-3-failed-to-start-bean-documentationpluginsboot).
Basically you have to include in the file `application.properties` the following configuration:

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
```

As it seems Spring Boot 2+ set as default the PathPathern-based matcher, while Spring Fox expects the Ant-based matcher.
The problem with this solution is that you cannot use Spring Actuator, since it uses PathPattern based URL matching. In this case, check this [Spring Fox issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3462).

Answer (score 1):

```
SwaggerConfig.java 


@Configuration  
//Enable Swagger  
@EnableSwagger2  
public class SwaggerConfig   
{  
//creating bean  
    
@Bean  
public Docket api()  
{  
//creating constructor of Docket class that accepts parameter DocumentationType  
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.demo.controller")).paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api.*")).build();  
}  
}  


And Application.properties file :

spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ant-path-matcher
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).